# Applet Permission Denied

Tags: java, applet

All
  I have signed all the jar files including appletviewer.jar also . i am running latest version of JDK . I was running and viewing applet successfully till today afternoon , but suddenly i am getting this exception now . i can not understand what is happening ...
please, help me asap.

```
exception: Permission denied: null.
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied: null
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied: null
Exception in thread "thread applet-applet.EmbeddedViewerApplet.class-3" java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied: http://localhost:8080/ExtraCare/resources/appletviewer.jar
    at sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter.setProgressFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.setupGrayBoxPainter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.showAppletException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank You
Mihir Parekh
+91 94266 21000 .

Comment: do you use any VCS? If so you can have a look what changes have been introduced.

Comment: You don't have the applet tag on an http URL, and the code on a file URL, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using FireFox?  Any chance you recently updated to version 3.6.14?

Check this out...

https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/pogo-and-other-java-pages-dont-work

Comment: Note.  That link now says 3.6.15 is released and fixes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to wrap your calls in a doPrivileged block. Beforehand, you might want to call checkPermission on the method you want to invoke. 
Here are two useful articles.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html

http://www.raditha.com/java/sandbox/unsigned.php

However, if you use jnlp deployment, System.setSecurityManager(null) should solve your problems and you will have more privileges of your applet, allowing you to effectively escape the browser sandbox without much hassle. Keep in mind though, that doing so is not only not a good practice, but actually does expose the user of your applet to malicious code.

Comment: Clearing the security manager removes security restrictions for all code running in the process. You need to be really sure that your code can never be repurposed to take down security in a process in which the security was necessary. Similarly, liberal sprinklings of doPrivileged can be problematic.

Comment: "However, if you use jnlp deployment, System.setSecurityManager(null) should solve your problems and you will have more privileges of your applet, ..".  There is no difference between the way an embedded applet and JWS launched app. work in this case.  Both must be trusted before they can call System.setSecurityManager(null), and doing so will have pretty much the same effect.